# Click to insert date value using input

Tags: jquery

I could not do that when put in a value being placed on the input attribute "data-value" here is my attempt:

```
$('.enviar').on('click', function(){
    var bla = $('input').val();
    $("#canPIE").data("values", bla);
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcC4A/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcC4A/2/)

```
$('.enviar').on('click', function(){

var bla = $('input').val();


  $("#canPie").attr("data-values", $("#canPie").attr("data-values") + "," + bla);


  drawPieChart('canPie');

});
```

Comment: @PatrickQ check the fiddle with the question. After going through it, I assumed that this is what the user is looking for.